# What is the number of ways to arrange bigrams from a list of $n$ numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a list of $n$ (distinct) numbers. What are the number of permutations of this list, such that at least one bigram from the original list is preserved in the permutation?

Example: if $n = 4$ and we have the list $[1,2,3,5]$, then the bigrams are $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$ and $[3,5]$. One valid permutation might be $[5, 2, 3, 1]$ since the bigram $[2, 3]$ is preserved. The permutation $[3,1,5,2]$ is invalid, since no bigram is preserved. Note that bigrams are order-sensitive, so $[2, 1]$ is not a bigram.

How many such permutations are there? I initially reasoned that there are $(n-1) \cdot (n-1)!$ permutations, since for each of $n - 1$ possible bigrams, we can arrange the $n-1$ elements (treat the bigram as one, conjoined element) in $(n-1)!$ ways. However, this double counts: if the bigram is $[1, 2]$ then one permutation would be $[1,2,3,5]$ and if the bigram is $[2, 3]$ it would also generate $[1,2,3,5]$. I'm wondering how to fix the overcounting issue.

Comment: there's nothing special about the list, only the value of $n$ matters - your list may as well be [1,2,3,4] with the valid permutation [4,2,3,1] and the invalid permutation [3,1,4,2].  this simplification might help.

Comment: I also recommend considering permutations of the sequence $(1, 2, 3, \ldots, n)$.  Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?